# How to create an element and output the value in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, for-loop

```js
function lookup(city,day){
    alert("I am seeing a city of " + city + " and a day of " + day);  // Remove. Only for testing
    var nday = parseInt(day);
    switch(nday){
        case 0: return sunday(city); break;
        case 1:
        case 2: return tuesday(city); break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        default: alert("Monterey, we have a problem!  I'm seeing a day of " + nday);
    }
}

function sunday(city){
    var returnString = "";
    switch(city){
        case "New York City":
        case "Honolulu":
        case "Hong Kong":
        case "Beijing":
        case "Tokyo":returnString = "MAS 975©Tuesday©20:00©14:00©$500.00"; return returnString; break;
        case "Ulaanbaatar":
        case "London":    
        default: alert("Destination invalid!  I'm seeing a destination of " + city); break;
    }
}

function tuesday(city){
    alert("I am seeing a city of " + city );    //  Remove. Only for testing purposes
    var returnString = "";
    switch(city){
        case "New York City": 
        case "Honolulu":
        case "Hong Kong":
        case "Beijing":
        case "Tokyo": returnString = "MAS 304©Tuesday©15:30©6:30©$650.00"; return returnString; break;
        case "Ulaanbaatar":
        case "London": returnString = "MAS 975©Tuesday©20:00©14:00©$500.00"; return returnString; break;   
        default: alert("Destination invalid!  I'm seeing a destination of " + city); break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Wei Wu Section A-->
    <title>I suppose it's time to get Formal</title>
    <style>
        form {padding: 10px; font: lust script, minion pro, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 24pt; background-color: azure;text-align: center;}
        .resultDec {
            font: tahoma, serif; 
            font-style: italic; 
            font-size: 16pt; 
            background-color: lightyellow; 
            line-height: 24pt;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
    </style>
    <script>
        function fullFunc(){
            display();
        }
        function flightInfo(){
            var travelDay = document.getElementsByClassName('travelDay');
            var des = document.getElementById("destination");
            var strDes = des.options[des.selectedIndex].text;
            for (var i =0; travelDay[i];i++){
                if (travelDay[i].checked) {
                        var getData = lookup(destination.value,travelDay[i].value);
                        var getDataList = getData.split("©");
                        alert(getDataList); 
                        /*for (i=0;i<getDataList.length;i++){
                            para = document.createElement("p");
                            node = document.createTextNode(getDataList[i]);
                            para.appendChild(node);
                            element = document.getElementById("divForAppend");
                            element.appendChild(para);
                            document.getElementById("airlineNum").innerHTML += getDataList[i] +"<br>";
                        }*/
                    }
                }
            }
        function display(){
            var first = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
            var last = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
            document.getElementById("forName").innerHTML = "Hello " + first + " " + last;
            //This part is for displaying your name


            var des = document.getElementById("destination");
            var strDes = des.options[des.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("forDes").innerHTML = "Your destination is " + strDes + ".";
            //This part is for displaying your destination


            var bDay = document.getElementById("date").value;
            document.getElementById("forBday").innerHTML = "Birthday: " + bDay;
            ageList = bDay.split("-");
            // alert(ageList); just for test
            var day = ageList[2];
            var month = ageList[1];
            var year = ageList[0];
            var today = new Date();
            var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
            var currentMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
            var currentday = today.getDate();
            var age = 0;
            if (month < currentMonth){
                age = currentYear - year;
                document.getElementById('forAge').innerHTML = "Age: " + age + " years old.";
            }else if (month == currentMonth && day <= currentday){
                age = currentYear - year;
                document.getElementById('forAge').innerHTML = "Age: " + age + " years old.";
            }else{
                age = currentYear - year - 1;
                document.getElementById('forAge').innerHTML = "Age: " + age + " years old.";
            }
            if (age<= 2) {
                document.getElementById("forAge").innerHTML += "<br>" + " The price for domestic flights (Hawaii and NYC) are free and international flights are only 10% ! "
            }
            //This part is for displaying your birthday AND age


            var radioButton = document.getElementsByName('gender');
            for (var i = 0; i < radioButton.length; i++){
                if (radioButton[i].checked){
                    document.getElementById("forGender").innerHTML = "Your gender: " + radioButton[i].value +"<br>" + "<br>" + "Your flight information: " + "<br>";
                    break;
                }
            }
            flightInfo();
        }
            //This part is for displaying your gender.

    </script>
    <script src="airport.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wholeForm">
    <form action="#" name="defineMe" autocomplete="off">        
    <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""><br>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""></label><br>
    <label>Birthday: <input type="date" id="date" name="date" value=""></label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Prefer not go disclose"> Prefer not to disclose<br>

    <select id="destination">
            <option> pick a distination </option>
            <option value="New York City">New York City</option>
            <option value="Honolulu">Honolulu</option>
            <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
            <option value="Beijing">Beijing</option>
            <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
            <option value="Ulaanbaatar">Ulaanbaatar</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>When you will travel?</legend>
        <div id="travelDay" class='todayTravel'>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay1" value="0" class="travelDay"> Sunday<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay2" value="1" class="travelDay"> Monday<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay3" value="2" class="travelDay"> Tuesday<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay4" value="3" class="travelDay"> Wednesday<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay5" value="4" class="travelDay"> Thursday<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay6" value="5" class="travelDay"> Friday<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="travelDay7" value="6" class="travelDay"> Saturday<br><br>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit (locally)" onclick="fullFunc()">
    </form>
    
    <div class="resultDec" id="divForAppend">
    <p id="forName"></p>
    <p id="forDes"></p>
    <p id="forBday"></p>
    <p id="forAge"></p>
    <p id="forGender"></p>
    <p id="forString"></p>
    <p id="airlineNum"></p>
    <p id="day"></p>
    <p id="departureTime"></p>
    <p id="arrivalTime"></p>
    <p id="price"></p>
    </div>
</div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

This code is basically used to use input from the users to determine which airline he/she is gonna take. The library is defined and can not be changed (given by our professor lol). And the user could choose multiple travelday at the same time.

What my question is that: by testing, my code works perfectly when I use "alert" or "console.log" I could see multiple output. The thing is: our professor wants us to split the information returned back from the js library and then output it into different lines.

What I tried to do is create new p tag and then append the new p into the  at the very bottom of the code, and my code is in the comment in the HTML (it has been commented out).

Once I use the commented-out code to display it on screen, I can no longer get multiple days information. For example, when I choose "Tuesday" and "Sunday" (because my testing data in js is only available on these two days), and I choose destination: "Tokyo", I could only get the info for Tuesday Tokyo.

So: how can I create new p tag in the for loop ( because I want to display all the info for each day that the user checked)? Thank you very much!!

Comment: to simplify your question, that is too big, can you show an example of desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would suggest you to use ES6 features of JavaScript. That would resolve some of the coding errors you have in your code. I also didn't understand exactly what output you were expecting.

I did have a look at the mentioned commented code above, found some coding errors. May be the below code might help you work on it.

I didn't optimize the code but just removed some errors in the flightInfo function, this might help you get what you need.

```
    function flightInfo(){
        var travelDay = document.getElementsByClassName('travelDay');
        var des = document.getElementById("destination");
        var strDes = des.options[des.selectedIndex].text;
        for (var i =0; travelDay[i];i++){
            if (travelDay[i].checked) {
                var getData = lookup(des.value,travelDay[i].value);
                if(typeof getData != 'undefined') {
                    let getDataList = getData.split("©");
                    //alert(getDataList); 
                    for (let j=0;j<getDataList.length;j++){
                        para = document.createElement("p");
                        node = document.createTextNode(getDataList[j]);
                        para.appendChild(node);
                        element = document.getElementById("divForAppend");
                        element.appendChild(para);
                        document.getElementById("airlineNum").innerHTML += getDataList[j] +"<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comments on some of the errors I found,

var getData = lookup(des.value,travelDay[i].value); -> you mentioned the variable destination, it should be des instead. Read about JavaScript hoisting issues. [here](http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/)

The variable getData can be undefined for the days, Wed, thurs, fri and Sat. Have to handle that variable too.

The main issue why you were always getting the same output was because you used the variable 'i' twice in both the for loops. I changed one to 'j'.

Didn't look into other issues. But I think there are more issues in the code. Not sure

Also, I would try to clear the paragraph tags inserted, if the user tries to resubmit the form again, the tags would be appended to the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I have to learn more about ES6 features of course... And it is the question of the variable used twice. It seems that I have misused it here because probably in Python, it's more flexible and I am learning them at the same time... anyway thanks a lot!